How to get return value 0 from ::write() for non blocking client tcp socket on linux?
I am trying to reproduce above condition.

Socket was closed and returned 0.
Buffer was not zero sized. Observed
Observed socket state was CLOSE_WAIT after write() return 0.
Server was shut down.
Solarflare card
TCP_NODELAY

I believe I saw such condition once by accident, but could not reproduce it with any combination.
Appreciate suggestions in advance.
NOTE:
This is not question can or cannot non-blocking write return zero, or what would zero mean. Such case was accidentally experienced first time ever. However I added logging and could not reproduce it with bunch of different scenarios. Now I am mere asking if anyone know a way to reproduce it.
The ::write part of code looks trivial(simplifying most non socket logic):
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
const uint64_t length=1000000;
char buffer[1000000];
while(true)
{
  ssize_t ret = ::write(fd, buffer, length);
  if (ret>=0)
  {
    std::cout<<"ret "<<ret<<std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    int errnum = errno;
    std::cout<<"errno "<<errnum<<std::endl;
    if (errnum != EAGAIN && errnum !== EINTR)
      break;
  }
  ::sleep(1); // 1 second.
}

Observation was:
after it printed "ret 0"
it keeps printing "errno 11" (EAGAIN)
and "netstat -anpc" showed
tcp        1      0 **.**.**.**:46298       **.**.**.***:****       CLOSE_WAIT  6622/./blabla


I don't think it can legitimately return 0 unless the buffer length is 0. It always returns the number of bytes that were written, or -1 if there was an error. If no bytes were written, it must be due to an error, so it returns -1.

@Barmar: If the amount of data which has been written to a socket is too much greater than the amount which has been read by code at the far end, having an attempted non-blocking write transmit zero bytes would seem cleaner than having it report an error, since errors would generally imply that a socket was in an unknown or permanently unusable state.

@supercat The sender doesn't wait for the receiver to read the data. write() simply puts the data into a buffer. If there's no room in the buffer, it returns -1 with errno == EAGAIN

And if there's room for some, but not all, of the data, it returns the number of bytes that were buffered.

@Barmar: Hmm... having non-blocking streams write 0 bytes seems cleaner than requiring a sender to special-case that (non-)error, but I've seen streams using both approaches.  With regard to buffering, the entity that sends data to a TCP socket will need to buffer it until the receiver has buffer space to accept it, and buffer space which gets used up on the receiver can't be freed until client code has read the data.

@supercat It doesn't usually come up. Applications using non-blocking streams usually use select() or epoll() to wait for space in the output buffer to become available. But it's true that they have to special-case EAGAIN (AKA EWOULDBLOCK) since it's a temporary error, not fatal. Also EINTR may need to be handled specially.

do you have the code - if so pls share, tks

Also see Is a return value of 0 from write(2) in C an error?

It makes no sense to ask how to reproduce something that shouldn't be possible in the first place. You claim that you observed this once, but I have to assume you were mistaken. If it actually happened it was a bug, and who knows which release had it or if it still exists?

@Barmar Yes, I can be wrong. Yes, it could be bug. However, asking questions are always good.
